# Python: Dealing with dictionary values that do not exist in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, key, keyerror

I'm new to python but have experience in perl. So I have a dictionary like this

```
d = { '123' : 'F'
      '124' : 'S'
      '125' : 'F'
    }
```

and I'm running a loop for a list which has the key values, but some may not exist in my dictionary. When I run the code I get an error

```
print(d[str(row[0])])


KeyError: '126'
```

Perl would never do this to me. Please help an ignorant programmer.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dict.get()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) that will never raise a `KeyError` exception:

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

```
print(d.get(str(row[0])))
```

Or, you can check if a key is in the dictionary before trying to get the value by the key:

```
key = str(row[0])
if key in d:
    print(d[key])
```

Or, you can also catch a `KeyError` exception:

```
key = str(row[0])
try:
    print(d[key])
except KeyError:
    print("Key '{}' not found".format(key)
```

Comment: But if you're going to go to the trouble to check, it's often more better to just catch the exception. And it's considered good python style: "It's easier to ask forgiveness than to get permission", says the dictum.

Comment: @alexis agreed, thank you, will include in the answer.

Comment: @alexis should have said "forgive me for it" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the prefererd way is

```
my_dict.get(key,None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is a little more object-oriented than Perl — so you can to easily derive your own `dict` sublcass that does whatever you want when an attempt is made to access a missing key. However it takes more effort to write hard-to-read code, but it can be done. For example:

```
class MyDict(dict): __missing__ = lambda _, k: '%s?' % k

d = MyDict((('123', 'F'), ('124', 'S'), ('125', 'F'),))

row = 126, 123, 124
print(d[str(row[0])])  # -> 126?
```

Comment: Don't do this: That's what `collections.defaultdict` is for.

Comment: alexis: Not quite the same. Unlike `defaultdict`, this doesn't add missing entries to the dictionary.